# How To remove Parent class base of child class by Prototype or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, class, prototype

I want to remove class on base of child class in html content.

```
<div class="mydds">
    <dt><label class="required"><em>*</em>Light Source</label></dt>
    <dd class="last">
        <div class="input-box">
            <select style="width:230px;" name="super_attribute[224]" id="attribute224" class="required-entry super-attribute-select remArro" onchange="return changeSku(224, this);" disabled="">
                <option value="226" data-label="led retrofit/fluo">LED Retrofit/Fluo</option>
             </select>
        </div>
    </dd>
</div>
```

In this code in select you can see a class remArro, and in `<dt><label class="required">`. I want to remove required class on base of remArro class, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.remArro').parents('.mydds').find('label').removeClass('required')
```

Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`$.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) in jQuery to find an ancestor with a specific selector. You'll need to get the closest common parent then find your target, since `label.required` is not the parent of the `.remArro` element.

```
$('.remArro').closest('.mydds').find('label').removeClass('.required')
```